# jbpm task form in another application

Tags: jboss, jbpm

I need your help to complete a requirement.

I have a process in jbpm 6.2 and this process has a task form.
I am querying the taskform with http://192.168.221.146:8080/jbpm-console/rest/task/21/showTaskForm. This returns the form url.
In my simple html page I am using that returned url into an iframe.
I am filling that form, now how can I post those values back to jbpm through REST to complete that task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way that worked for me was using this javascript:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("myframe");
frame.contentWindow.postMessage('{"action":"completeTask", "taskId":"' + taskId + '"}', url);
```

Where `taskId` is id of your task and `url` is form url.